# Logging ongoing Fiddler-captured traffic

Tags: logging, httpresponse, fiddler

I am capturing traffic for a third party application and I wish to output the Fiddler logs to be consumed in Splunk.

The calls are not logged in the application's current logs so capturing the response from the server seems to be the easiest way to find out the duration of specific calls.

I see I can create an [extension](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Save-And-Load-Traffic/Tasks/LogToLocalDB) to the rules that will output the logs the way I want, yet it does not look like Fiddler is meant for this constant capturing as I do not see anything in their [CLI arguments](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/commandlineparams) that lets me set filters.

Am I missing some functionality in the tool or should I switch tools to something designed with this in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you'd want to use something like [FiddlerCore](http://www.fiddler2.com/core/) for special purposes like this.

Comment: It looks like you have to code FiddlerCore into the application during development time - I'm working on a closed source application though. Or are you suggesting adding FiddlerCode into Splunk directly?

Comment: Typically, you write your own host applet for FiddlerCore which filters out traffic you don't care about and so forth. This applet captures traffic from whatever applications you want, just like Fiddler does.